# Can't save into input buffer changes range.insertNode(node)

Tags: selection, undo, execcommand, addrange

Use selection.addRange(range) for insert html near default text, but this action doesn't save into history of input, and when i use ctrl+z, undo previous action, not change(insertNode)
I need, that when I use ctrl+z, action `undo` detach my html, which i insert before
i'l do this like that:

```
let node = target_fragment.appendChild(target.firstChild);
                range.insertNode(target_fragment);
                range = range.cloneRange();
                range.setStartAfter(node);
                range.collapse(true);
                selection.removeAllRanges();
                selection.addRange(range);
```

Comment: p.s. if you use historyUndo when add tag after question, you destroy previous tag, stackoverflow has same problem

Comment: it works normaly, then use execCommand('insertHtml') with range.setStart/setEnd, but needs be carefully with listner, and capture unwanted events